# Value of type 'Observable<String>' has no member 'bind'

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am trying to bind a string value in ViewModel to a label in my ViewController but I am getting following error:

> Value of type 'Observable' has no member 'bind'
>   My code for binding in ViewController:

```
self.viewModel.myNum
        .map( { $0 })
        .bind(to: serialNumberLabel.rx.text)
```

myNum is defined in viewModel as following:

```
var myNum: Observable<String>
```

No I have 2 problems here:
1. Above error in ViewController
2. Initializing myNum in ViewModel
I tried following for initializing myNum but I am getting error:

```
materialNum = Observable<String>("")
```

Answer (score 18):

I think that you might forget to use `import RxCocoa`.

For me the code works, but `.map({ $0 })` is redundant because it returns the same value it gets, and you of course forgot to add `.disposed(by:)` at the end:

```
self.viewModel.myNum
    .bind(to: serialNumberLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by:self.disposeBag)
```

About the initialization you might do as Valérian said:

```
materialNum = Observable.just("My string")
```

But if you change observable later you will need again bind the label text.

EDIT: Example (author request)

@pankaj, I would recommend you to download [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) project from GitHub and check their playgrounds.

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class MyViewModel: ReactiveCompatible {

    fileprivate lazy var _text = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "My Initial Text")

    var text: String {
        get { return _text.value }
        set { _text.accept(newValue) }
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: MyViewModel {

    var text:Observable<String> {
        return base._text.asObservable()
    }

    var setText: AnyObserver<String> {
        return Binder<String>(base, binding: { viewModel, value in
            viewModel.text = value
        }).asObserver()
    }
}
```

Binder `setText` in `Reactive` extension above is not required in your case but may be useful in other cases.

Then you can bind:

```
self.viewModel.rx.text
    .bind(to: serialNumberLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by:self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help yes I am now able to run it but I am not getting data in my serialNumberLabel

Comment: I use Observable.just to send the data to label from ViewModel, also would you suggest me to use anything else then map?

Comment: @pankaj, `Observable.just("My string")` was just an example, "`just()` takes an argument and sends it as `next` and then it sends `completed` right after the next" ([source](http://adamborek.com/creating-observable-create-just-deferred/)), maybe you change that value after the observable returns the value, if your value won't change in time I suggest to hardcode it, if it will be changed you should assign to `materialNum` more complicated observable wich generates the appropriate text, or you may use `PublishSubject` or `Variable` to change text from ViewModel.

Comment: ok, probably this is the reason it is not listening for all changes to my variable. So if I use PublishSubject will I be able to listen to all the changes to my variable in ViewModel? Also can you please share an example of PublishSubject being used similar to my requirement.

Comment: And about the `map` I just think that the map is not needed there because you don't transform the value returned by myNum to any other value there, you are mapping the value on the same value. your `map` just gets the myNum and returns it again. What for?

Comment: yes you are right, I can remove map here, I just need to update my label with data from ViewModel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164398/discussion-between-typowykodel-and-pankaj).

Comment: this is too much trouble only for update a label. does not justify.

Comment: similar error if you accidentally use bindTo() instead of bind(to:)

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is for `Relays` (and `Variable` which is deprecated !).

Simply use `subscribe`

```
self.viewModel.myNum.subscribe(serialNumberLabel.rx.text)
```

You need to use one of the existing methods to create your observable:

```
materialNum = Observable.just("My string")
```

Comment: There's no problem binding to rx.text - It is for any ObserverType, and `rx.text` which is a `ControlProperty`, is one :)